# Setting default values for Personal Campaign Pages

Tags: civicontribute, personal-campaign-pages

We have a student organization where all students are being asked to help solicit contributions to a campaign.  Was hoping to create personal campaign pages (PCP) for each student.  Rather than having each student create their own individual title, message, etc. for their PCP, I'd like to default values that they can then override if they choose to do so.

Is there any straightforward way to auto-create the PCPs with default values for a list of current users within a group?  Anyone tackled this one before that can point in the best direction?

Using CiviCRM 4.5.4 on Drupal.

Comment: I've encountered this problem before as well!  One tricky bit is that PCPs require a CMS user account for each person - which isn't really necessary for all use cases.  I only had about 12 PCPs to do, but if I had more I'd experiment with creating them via the API.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about API - But you can create an script against database that would be easier you can insert values into the table called civicrm_pcp just make an entry using different contact Id this will be faster - just create a single PCP first and copy the value for the rest of contact

Answer (score 0):

No, Contribution Page API does not support PCP (or other 'extras' like Widget,Tell-a-friend, etc.) but that would be a great addition!

Answer (score 0):

An API for Personal Campaign Pages is in development. You can follow the issue here:

https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-18195